# Moving domain - 301 Redirect with data

Tags: redirect, seo, cross-domain, url-parameters, http-referer

I am moving from **d(omain)1** to **d2**.

I want to have R301 from **d1** to **d2** and on **d2** I want to be able to know, that the user was redirected from d1 and did not come straight to **d2** (not neccessarily only *direct trafic by definition*, but just not via redirect on **d1**.

I prefer solution that does not create more "problems" like SEO issues when using URL params.

So ideal is HTTP_REFERER or other header, but it seems not to work. Or is there a solution (at all... apart from URL params)?

Furthermore if I eventually have to use URL params, would it be sufficient to set ...rel="canonical"... on **d2** webpages, so that Google sees "mypage.php?redirected=true" the same as "mypage.php" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RFC doesn't specify any referrer-specific behaviour in status 301 definition. If you control the web server in d1 you can [add an header via Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_headers.html) or via your favourite sever side language.

If you want to go with the URL params way, the canonical tag should be enough to prevent any duplication issue with Google.

Comment: thanks, maybe it was not clear, but 'd1.com' and 'd2.com' are different second-level domains so the 301 is cross domain (so it will be external redirect right?). AFAIK no headers will be passed to the new browser GET request.